# When adding a point to a series, the marker does not display (It's hidden by other area splines)

Tags: highcharts

I've added a series to a chart:

```
chart.addSeries({
    id: 'child-bmi-scores',
    name: 'Child\'s BMI',
    color: 'blue',
    type: 'scatter',
    showInLegend: false,
    data: [ [3, 20], [10, 16] ]
});
```

and later on, I want to add a point to that series. So I've done that:

```
var chart = chartContainer.highcharts();

var series = chart.get('child-bmi-scores');

series.addPoint(
    {
        x: 16.5,
        y: 19,
        height: 456,
        weight: 789,
        ageYears: 16,
        ageMonths: 6
    } 
);
```

The point does get added, but the trouble is that the blue marker is not visible.

You can see from the image below, the two visible blue squares are from the initial `data: [ [3, 20], [10, 16] ]`, and you can see the crosshairs focussing in on the newly added point - it's definitely there, but without the crosshairs hovering over the point, you just don't see it.

[image]

The other curves that you can see are all `areaspline` series also on the chart.

I'm wondering if the Z-order has got messed up and the new point is somehow behind one of the area splines?

I created a fiddle that demonstrates what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/j08L6afh/

So before you click the "Add point" button, hover around and prove there are only two scatter points. Then, if you click the button at the top, then it will add the point, you'll be able to find it by hovering your mouse near and getting the crosshairs, but you won't see the marker.

**UPDATE**
I removed the curves off the chart, so that the scatter was the only series:
http://jsfiddle.net/j08L6afh/1/

Now you can see it works as expected, so it would appear to be being hidden by one or more of the curves. How can I make the new point at the front?

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this by doing a `.push` onto an array of measurements, and reinitialising the entire chart.

It worked, but I imagine there is a better way?